# popup keyboard key with more then one character - android

Tags: android, keyboard, key

Is there a way to create a popup keyboard with more than one character appears in? 
(my label not show me the options keys from the keyboard)
this is my code in the xml file:

```
enter code here

  <Keyboard
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:keyWidth="15%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/popup_key_height"

    >
     <Row
        android:rowEdgeFlags="top|bottom"
        >
       <Key
            android:keyLabel="@string/popular_domain_1"
            android:keyOutputText="@string/popular_domain_1"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
             />
       <Key
            android:keyLabel="@string/popular_domain_2"
            android:keyOutputText="@string/popular_domain_2"/>
```

in my popup label I do not see anything just an empty cube... tnx!

Comment: Swiftkey does this, so I don't see why not. Please show us your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're asking for the popup if you long click the key?

There is another xml attribute called popupCharacters where you can state the extra characters and then you only need a layout for them in the attribute popupKeyboard. Like this:

```
    <Key
        android:codes="0x0628"
        android:keyLabel="&#x0628;"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_keyboard"
        android:popupCharacters="&#x067E;"/>
```